# django how to work with templates

Tags: python, django

I'm practising Django now, and I'm stuck. When I run:

```
>>> from django import template
>>> t = template.Template('hi')
```

Gives me:

> ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.

Any idea what causes this? What should I do?

Comment: What are you doing exactly to generate this output?  What OS, how are you starting Django?  Did you get a sample project to work?

Comment: no , as i said I'm only practicing . and I'm studying (Templates) from apress's (definitive guide to django )book . im using windows 7 64x

Comment: You should go through the official tutorial first, it's quite good and covers all the basics: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/), you have to do the following:

> When you use Django, you have to tell it which settings you're using. Do this by using an environment variable, `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.
>
> The value of `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` should be in Python path syntax, e.g. `mysite.settings`. Note that the settings module should be on the Python import search path.

Answer (score 4):

Django is designed to work within a project, which contains a file named `settings.py`.  Rather than just importing it on the command line, you should work through the tutorial, which shows you how to create a project and its apps.

If you just want a quick start, you need to execute this on the command line:

```
django-admin.py startproject test_project
```

This will create a directory named `test_project` with the needed files.  Within that directory, you can execute the command:

```
./manage.py shell
```

which will get you a Python shell with the settings module properly loaded.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer , no need for duplicate answer i just removed mine :)